# View causing Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function error when providing where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm having an odd thing occurring in one of my views. Initially, I have a view that does the following:

```
 SELECT id, CAST((CASE WHEN 
                  LEN(line) = 1 
                  THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(line)), '-1') 
                  ELSE 
                  ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(line, 1, (CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), 
                  line) - 1)))), '-1') 
           END) AS varchar(MAX)) AS ObjMarker
 FROM  dbo.tblM2016_RAW_Current_Import_File
 WHERE ((CASE WHEN 
          LEN(line) = 1 
          THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(line)), '') 
          ELSE 
          LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([line], 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), [line])))) 
          END) <> CHAR(9)) 
          AND 
          ((CASE WHEN 
          LEN(line) = 1 
          THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(line)), '') 
          ELSE 
          LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([line], 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), [line])))) 
          END) NOT LIKE '%*%') 
          AND 
          ((CASE WHEN 
          LEN(line) = 1 
          THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(line)), '') 
          ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([line], 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), 
          [line])))) END) <> '')
```

And it works fine. However, I have another view which uses the results of the above view, shown below:

```
 SELECT curr.id
 ,curr.ObjMarker
 ,Nxt.id AS NxtID
 ,Nxt.ObjMarker AS NxtObjMarker
 ,Nxt.id - curr.id - 2 AS OFFSET
 ,curr.id + 1 AS StrtRec
 ,Nxt.id - 1 AS EndRec
 FROM  dbo.vwM2016_RAW_Import_File_Object_Line_Markers AS curr 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 dbo.vwM2016_RAW_Import_File_Object_Line_Markers AS Nxt ON 
 Nxt.id =
 (SELECT MIN(id) AS Expr1
 FROM   dbo.vwM2016_RAW_Import_File_Object_Line_Markers AS source
 WHERE (id > curr.id))
 WHERE curr.ObjMarker <> '0'
```

And apparently, if I leave the `WHERE curr.ObjMarker <> '0'` in the second query, it gives the error

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But if I remove `WHERE curr.ObjMarker <> '0'` it returns the result set without error.

Could this be a problem with the query optimizer not doing operations in order? I've checked the rows where 0 occurs for any special characters in an editor and I couldn't find any hidden whitespace characters or anything.

Comment: For the reader who like me has to look it up CHAR(9) returns a TAB character. If this were my code I'd be looking for rows where the `line` field is more than one character long but doesn't contain a tab. In any such case your code will be attempting to find the left -1 characters.

Comment: But why does the problem occur only when the "outer" WHERE clause is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee of the order the criteria in your select statements will be evaluated, and SQL Server does not short circuit. Predicate pushdown can also happen for any criteria SQL Server estimates to be useful -- so you can't assume that a certain criteria will always be evaluated before something else.

Comment: Could you please translate that for the given problem? :)

Comment: I think the thought here is that SQL Server may be trying to evaluate the where clause in the outer view against the 'line' field before the where clause of the inner view is applied. Thus the error may really relate to rows which aren't returned in the first view.

Comment: Yes, exactly, as far as I know, predicate pushdown can cause anything in the where clause to be evaluated first, even when it comes from the where clause referring the the view, even before the criteria in the view itself has been evaluated -- and if there's some rows that would be "outside" the view, they can still be evaluated against the given criteria.

Comment: I solved the problem by inserting the results of the first view into a table first, then referencing that table in the other view.

I'm hoping this will solve the problem as the second view no longer needs to rely on the 1st view to be evaluated first since the first views results will be in a table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this expression:

```
 ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(line, 1, (CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), 
                  line) - 1)))), '-1')
```

If [line] does not contain a Char(9), the CharIndex field returns 0.  This turns the substring expression into SUBSTRING(line,1,-1), which is invalid because the length cannot be a negative number.

When not used in the WHERE clause, the expression is not evaluated until after the other filters are applied and the result set is reduced.  At least one of the filters in the view eliminate the rows without tabs, so the expression never operates on those rows.

However, when the expression is used in the WHERE clause, it is combined with the view filters and evaluated in the order that SQL Server determines is best for performance.  Unfortunately, some of the rows without tabs are still part of the result set when this is evaluated, causing the result to fail.

A possible fix, add an explicit test in your case statement (in the first view where you define `objMarker`) to address rows that do not contain tabs.

```
          WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), line) = 0 THEN '-1'
```